# Can't compare a values in access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Here is the code, the field Автомобили.Описание is instance of Short Text in a result table of a Автомобили query

```
SELECT Автомобили.НомVIN, Автомобили.ФИО, Автомобили.РегНомер, Автомобили.Описание
FROM Автомобили
WHERE (((Year(Now()) - CInt([Автомобили].[Описание]) = 40)))
ORDER BY Автомобили.ФИО, Автомобили.Описание;
```

The thing is that if I want to just compare values in WHERE clause only with '=' it seems fine, everything works properly. But when I try to compare them by '<' or '>' or '<=' or '>=" the Access throws an error "Datatype mismatch in criteria expression". What is wring with it?

Comment: Try `CInt(Year(Now()) - CInt([Автомобили].[Описание]))<=40`

Answer (score 0):

`Year()` returns an Integer, so your criteria examples are correct and perfectly valid. So, it is something else.

Try to *leave out* the ordering or sort on the numeric value:

```sql
SELECT 
    Автомобили.НомVIN, 
    Автомобили.ФИО, 
    Автомобили.РегНомер, 
    Автомобили.Описание
FROM 
    Автомобили
WHERE
    Year(Date()) - CInt([Автомобили].[Описание]) = 40
ORDER BY 
    Автомобили.ФИО, 
    CInt(Автомобили.Описание);
```